# Navigation Architecture Component fragment replace issue

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I have three fragment like fragmetnA, fragmentB and fragmentC. Now using Navigation architecture  component 
I have switch

FragmentA -> FrgmentB -> Fragment C now from fragmentC I opend Fragment A so now navigation flow looks like this

**FrgmentB -> Fragment C -> FragmentA**

instead of

**FragmentA -> FrgmentB -> Fragment C -> FragmentA** so How to acheive this kind of navigation flow using 
navigation architecture component.

Comment: When you reach FragmentA again, what should be opened next FragmentB?
Chain should be
Fragment C -> FragmentA -> FrgmentB
or 
FrgmentB -> Fragment C -> FragmentA -> FrgmentB ?

Comment: FragmentA set as start destination?

Comment: FragmentA is start destination and I want result : FragmentB->FragmentC ->FragmentA